# Return first match in Java 8 stream (similar to _.find)

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream, lodash

I have a static method that identifies a matching type from a set using java 8 streams.

Rather than using `.filter` and `.findAny`, I'd like to use a method similar to lodash's [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find), that "Iterates over elements of collection and returns the first element predicate returns truthy for."

a "find" type method would presumably make the code more performant and concise

```
public static List<Class> types = Arrays.asList(
    Contact.class,
    Response.class,
    Request.class   
);

public static Optional<Class> resolveTypeFromFieldNames(Set<String> itemFields) {
    return types
        .stream()
        .filter(itemType -> {
            Set<String> fields = Arrays.stream(itemType.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(f -> !f.isSynthetic())
                    .map(Field::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            return itemFields.equals(fields);
        })
        .findAny();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, what you already have is *totally* the way to do it, and it's not actually any less performant.  `filter` is performed lazily, which means that the predicate only gets evaluated until the first element matching the predicate is found.  It does *not* evaluate the predicate for any more elements than it has to.

What you have is the way the Stream framework designers intended you to do this operation.

Comment: @youurayy: No.  That is not what filter does.  The answer is correct.

Comment: @youurayy: It's easy enough to demonstrate this for yourself with code like [this](https://ideone.com/9xlRE2), which demonstrates that `filter(...).findAny()` does not go through the whole collection, only as many elements as necessary until a matching element is found.  If it processed the whole collection, it would print `testing 4` and `testing 5`, and it does not.

Comment: WOW sir thanks for proving me wrong -- I had no idea that .findAny() can communicate its presence upstream to the .filter() !!!
(I deleted my original comment as to not confuse ppl who don't expand all the comments)
thanks again!